# State update being overridden by another (previous) state update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I know this seems as unusual example, but still I can't seem to explain precisely why do I never see `valueB` printed on console after I click the `div`?

Note that since I am calling the two set state calls in a `setTimeout`, **they are not batched**.

```js
function App() {
  let [a, setA] = React.useState();
  let [b, setB] = React.useState();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Entering useEffect', a, b);

    return () => {
      console.log('Entering cleanup', a, b);

      setA(null);
      setB(null);
    };
  }, [a, b]);

  console.log('Render', a, b);

  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setA('valueA');
          setB('valueB');
        }, 100);
      }}
    >
      <h1>Test App</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Calling the state *updaters* in the effect cleanup just seems wrong to me. Is this for testing purposes only? If you remove those, you'll gradually get `a` and `b` filled with values. So it might very well be the cause of the *problem* and the question would then be is it *acceptable* to update the state from a cleanup function? I couldn't find any advice for or against it, did you?

Comment: @Yoshi Yes as I mentioned I also know that it happens because of `setB(null)` but I was interested in more exact steps as to what happens and why is `valueB`never showing up in console logs. PS No I haven't seen advice saying not to use set state in a cleanup function.

Comment: Unusual example, but it appears that since the value of `a` changes first, it fires the `useEffect` twice (once by clicking, and again by the useEffect cleanup) before the value of `b` changes. By the time it calls `setB` in the timeout it has been overridden twice by newer updates. This [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/useeffect-example-zkecn?file=/src/App.js) demonstrates that React is queuing state updates in a way to prevent `b`'s value from being stale ("hello") when using a **timeout**.

Comment: @MattCarlotta but doesn't it seem strange that `setB` from timeout seems to be the last one called, and yet it gets overriden by `setB` from cleanup function which seems to me should have been called before it?

Comment: I think the answer should be, as the official guidance also says: "never perform state updates in the cleanup function", because the cleanup function is also triggered as a result of processing state updates.

Comment: @PeterB Does the official docs say it? Do you have a link?

Comment: Pretty sure it has to deal with both `a` and `b` being memoized arguments of the same  `useEffect`. Since `a` changes first, the `b` state is never updated by its state updater. If you separate the two states into two separate `useEffect`s, then both values are updated by their state updaters. Updated [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/useeffect-example-zkecn?file=/src/App.js), comment out the single useEffect and uncomment the two separate useEffects.

Comment: On the same note, if you invoke `setB` before `setA`, the inverse happens, where `setA` becomes stale .

Comment: @MattCarlotta I am failing to follow your point in previous comment, what do you mean memoized arguments of same useEffect?

Comment: @giorgimoniava Not at my PC so I can't search optimally, but I found this: https://dev.to/otamnitram/react-useeffect-cleanup-how-and-when-to-use-it-2hbm

Comment: @PeterB That's different, it doesn't say not to call setState in cleanup function. Calling state updater in unmounted component is a different thing.

Comment: I meant `a` and `b` are dependencies of the same `useEffect`. The useEffect will only be invoked when one of the dependencies changes. It appears that `a` changes first, and therefore `setB` gets ignored because it's stale  by the time its invoked (again, the useEffect is called **twice** before `setB` -- `b` is set to `goodbye` **twice**),

Comment: @MattCarlotta I am not following you again, but my **only concern** was that I was expecting `valueB` to appear at least in output of `console.log`. I think this discussion can become difficult now, because there maybe something else going on under the hood on how react sequences these calls in this case.

Comment: @MattCarlotta The reason why in the example with two useEffects we see `hello` (of B) printed at least in `console.log`, is now there is no call to **both** `setA` and `setB` in the cleanup function, and maybe now react sequences these calls differently.

Comment: @giorgimoniava Exactly my point. My guess is that the `setB` within the timeout becomes stale and therefore its value is ignored when useEffect updates its value twice.  A better question is: **Why do you need to update state to then immediately override it within a useEffect cleanup?** This approach results in the UI flashing.

Comment: @MattCarlotta I agree in practice you should unlikely need to use such code. Just I encountered it - was modifying some function and didn't know it was also used as a cleanup function. So it just seemed (and still seems) strange that I never saw `valueB` printed in `console.log`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally `useEffect` and its cleanup are called asynchronously (on another stack) after render. But if you call `setState` in a timer and there are `useEffect` callbacks, they are invoked eagerly but all accumulated state change from cleanup is called **after** `setState` that invoked this operation.

So in your example when `setTimeout` handler is called:

- when calling `setA`: `a` state is changed and two state changes from cleanup are added to *pending state change* queue
- when calling `setB`: first `valueB` is applied to `b` and then `null` from the cleanup (it's kind of *batched* here)

This tries to imitate the behaviour when state updates are actually batched like in click handlers (first apply state updates from the click handler and then from `useEffect`).

You can see what's happening more clearly when you use updater functions:

```js
function App() {
  Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log("**** another stack ****"));
  console.log("before useStateA");
  let [a, setA] = React.useState();
    console.log("between useStates");
  let [b, setB] = React.useState();
    console.log("after useStateB");
  

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Entering useEffect', a, b);

    return () => {
      console.log('Entering cleanup', a, b);

      setA(() => (console.log("setting a to null from cleanup"), null));
      setB(() => (console.log("setting b to null from cleanup"), null));
    };
  }, [a, b]);

  console.log('Render', a, b);

  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log("****timer start****");
          setA(() => (console.log("setting a to valueA from timer"), "valueA"));
          console.log("between timer setters");
          setB(() => (console.log("setting b to valueB from timer"), "valueB"));
          console.log("****timer end****");
        }, 100);
      }}
    >
      <h1>Test App</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Indeed by using *functional set state* now we can better see that `setB` from cleanup is fired after `setB` from timeout, which probably explains why this happens. So this doesn't seem to be a react bug I suppose right? Though it was bit odd behavior if you are not familiar with it I suppose.

Comment: no, it's not a bug. Effects should be called asynchronously after render. If it's not possible because there's another synchronous render they are called as late as possible.

Comment: I know effects are called asynchronously, just the fact that react would batch updates in such a way in this case (calling `setB` from cleanup after `setB` from timeout) wasn't apparent.